# Calling the Menu Title within wp_nav_menu array function

Tags: menus

Been struggling with this for a little while. I want to call a menu but include the title of the menu above the menu list. The basic code I have is as follows -

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => 'rmm-footer',
'theme_location'  => 'resources'
));
?>
```

This produces a list as follows -

Menu Item 1
Menu Item 2
Menu Item 3

But I want it to go as follows -

TITLE 
Menu Item 1
Menu Item 2
Menu Item 3

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `wp_get_nav_menu_name()` to get the menu name: `$name = wp_get_nav_menu_name( 'resources' );` (credit to @merhawi-fissehaye, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/323653/48203).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not get the menu title using `wp_nav_menu()`, you need to get the menu object as follow:

```
//Change with the ID of your menu
$menu_ID = 5;
$nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_ID );
// then echo the name of the menu
echo $nav_menu->name;
```

With the above code, you can insert the menu name in `wp_nav_menu()` using `items_wrap` parameter. For example:

```
$menu_ID = 5;
$nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_ID );
wp_nav_menu( array(
                 'theme_location'  => 'resources',
                 'container'       => 'div',
                 'container_class' => 'rmm-footer',
                 'items_wrap'      => '<ul><li id="item-id">'.$nav_menu->name.'</li>%3$s</ul>'
             )
);
```

Comment: If it wroked and answered your question, please, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not rely on menu Id, my solution will resolve dynamically the attached menu for the current location.

1- First we need to define a function that look for menu in our functions.php :

```
function monoprog_get_menu_by_location($location) {
    if(empty($location)) return false;

    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if(!isset($locations[$location])) return false;

    return get_term( $locations[$location], 'nav_menu' );
}
```

2- Then let's display the title of the menu displayed in any location we want :

```
$menu_obj = monoprog_get_menu_by_location('menufooterleft');
echo "<h3>".esc_html($menu_obj->name)."</h3>";
```

just replace '**menufooterleft**' with the location registered in your theme.