# How do I get the name of a menu in WordPress?

Tags: menus

I'm currently setting up a sidebar menu with multiple menus and sections. Each section with the title (the menu name) and a bunch of links underneath (the menu items) - I printed the items, but how do I print the menu name?

Thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access the menu metadata using the `wp_get_nav_menu_object` function

BY NAME:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object("my mainmenu" );
```

BY SLUG:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object("my-mainmenu" );
```

The return object as follows:

```
 Object (
   term_id => 4
   name => My Menu Name
   slug => my-menu-name
   term_group => 0
   term_taxonomy_id => 4
   taxonomy => nav_menu
   description => 
   parent => 0
   count => 6
 )
```

To display the name:

```
echo $menu->name;
```

Comment: You are already supplying the name, why would you want to get it again? Each time he changes the menu for another or updates the menu name in the back-end, he will have to update those values.

Comment: @DavidLee I don't get it why you discarded my answer, the idea is the same, I just provided the possible parameter accepted by `wp_get_nav_menu_object` function, that is it.

Comment: If you'd also like you can access the menu meta data by supplying the ID of the menu as follows `$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object ('id');`

Comment: think about it, you are saying that to get the `menu name` you need the `menu name`, same with the ID

Comment: Hey David, I think you're making a great point - but I don't quite understand it. Could you explain a bit more in your answer?

Comment: can  you point what part you dont understand please? the footer name changes when you assign another menu, so its better to get the name using the location, its like `get the name of the menu that its in the footer location`

Answer (score 30):

On WordPress version 4.9.0 and above you can use

```
wp_get_nav_menu_name($location)
```

[wp_nav_menu_name](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_name/) for more

Comment: Exactly what i searched for +1 … should be the accepted answer

Comment: This answer should be surfaced to the top or marked as the current correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the name like this, using the menu location, so if the menu is updated or you assign other menu you dont have to update anything here:

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); //get all menu locations
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations['name_of_the_menu_location']);//get the menu object

echo $menu->name; // name of the menu
```

the `'name_of_the_menu_location'` is the one you use to output a menu using `wp_nav_menu`

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu(array(
          'theme_location' => 'footer'//this value
     ));
?>
```